# Can't figure out what's wrong with my if statement in JavaScript [Update Sept 1st It appears my for loop is running twice, how do I fix?]

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

```js
var MarkUpChecker = (function iffe() {
    'use strict';
    var URLS = {
            'foo': 'http://foo.com',
            'bar': 'http://bar.com',
            'baz': 'http://baz.com',
            'yay': 'http://www.yay.com',
            'blargh': 'http://www.blargh.com'
        },

        publicAPI;

    function getURL() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            return URLS[arguments[i]];
        }
    }

    publicAPI = {

        addURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
                URLS[arguments[i]] = arguments[i + 1];
            }
            console.dir(URLS);
            return URLS;
        },
        addTag: function() {
            var doc = document,
                internal_h1 = doc.querySelectorAll('.internal_h1'),
                sheet = doc.createElement('style');
            for (var i = 0; i < internal_h1.length; i++) {
                internal_h1[i].innerHTML = '<h1>' + internal_h1[i].innerHTML + '</h1>';
                sheet.innerHTML = 'h1 {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; font-weight: 200!important; font-size: 22px !important; color: #333; margin: 3px 0px 6px; line-height: 24px !important;};'
                doc.body.appendChild(sheet);
            }
        },

        searchDoc: function() {
            function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
                referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
            }

            var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
                emailUrl = /img\//gi,
                tsUrl = /\/REPSuite\/static\/html\/inews_archives\/img\//gi,
                newstr = '',
                doc = document,
                container,
                container_id,
                container_links,
                container_images,
                documentTableWrapper,
                docBodyFirstChild,
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP;

            if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
                container = doc.createElement('div');
                container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
                container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
                container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
                container_id = doc.getElementById('container');
                docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP = doc.getElementsByClassName('flexTile')[4];


                if (nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    insertAfter(container, nodeToTargetToInsertLP);
                } else {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);
                }


            } else {
                container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
            }
            container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
                if (arguments[0] == "foo" || arguments[1] == "bar") {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/news/');
                } else {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/alt_news/');

                }
            }

            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = container_links[j];

                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) {
                        parser = document.createElement('a');
                        parser.href = link.href;

                        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                        newPathName = parser.pathname;


                        if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                            newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                            newstr = newPathName;
                            link.href = newstr;

                        }
                    } else {
                        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

My problem is my conditional doesn't seem to add the target `_self` attribute to a `href` based on a condition like I think it should.

This is an excerpt of a function which can be found in the snippet above.

```
        for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
            url = getURL(arguments[i]);
            for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                link = container_links[j];

                if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) { //problem seems to be here
                    parser = document.createElement('a');
                    parser.href = link.href;

                    link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                    newPathName = parser.pathname;


                    if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                        newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                        newstr = newPathName;
                        link.href = newstr;

                    }
                } else {
                    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                }
            }

        }
```

To give you some background the script's main function is to automate redundant tasks I have to do weekly to a newsletter which is repurposed to a static web-page/landing page:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://foo.com/path/to_page.aspx"> 
    <img src="img/some_image.jpg">
</a>
```

The script goes through the DOM, looks for URLS which match a condition and strips out the base URL, some of the pathname and applies target `_self` to the `href`

It also changes the pathnames of my images!

In the HTML I call this function which accepts a string:

```
    MarkUpChecker.searchURL('foo', 'bar');
```

That string represents the URL I would like to target and to have the changes applied  :

```
    var URLS = {
        'foo': 'http://foo.com',
        'bar': 'http://bar.com',
        'baz': 'http://baz.com',
        'yay': 'http://www.yay.com',
        'blargh': 'http://www.blargh.com'
    },
```

This function is used to cycle through the object:

```
    function getURL() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            return URLS[arguments[i]];
        }
    }
```

And lastly this is the `searchURL` function:

```
 searchDoc: function() {
            function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
                referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
            }

            var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
                emailUrl = /img\//gi,
                tsUrl = /\/REPSuite\/static\/html\/inews_archives\/img\//gi,
                newstr = '',
                doc = document,
                container,
                container_id,
                container_links,
                container_images,
                documentTableWrapper,
                docBodyFirstChild,
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP;

            if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
                container = doc.createElement('div');
                container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
                container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
                container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
                container_id = doc.getElementById('container');
                docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
                nodeToTargetToInsertLP = doc.getElementsByClassName('flexTile')[4];


                if (nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    insertAfter(container, nodeToTargetToInsertLP);
                } else {
                    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
                    container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
                    doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);
                }


            } else {
                container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
            }
            container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
                if (arguments[0] == "foo" || arguments[1] == "bar") {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/news/');
                } else {
                    container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/alt_news/');

                }
            }

            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = container_links[j];

                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) {
                        parser = document.createElement('a');
                        parser.href = link.href;

                        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                        newPathName = parser.pathname;


                        if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                            newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                            newstr = newPathName;
                            link.href = newstr;

                        }
                    } else {
                        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

What I have observed via the debugger is while it **does** strip out the path name it applies target `_blank` to all the `hrefs`

Also—The funny thing is the script works in another context/environment which doesn't need to go through this part of the code:

```
 if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
    newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
    newstr = newPathName;
    link.href = newstr;

}
```

It works perfectly in that case.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE August 29th, 2016**

Someone mentioned this to try this:

```
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
    urls[i] = getURL(arguments[i]);
}
for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
    link = container_links[j];
    if (urls.every(function(url) {
        return link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1;
    }) {
        // none of the urls matched the link
    } else {
        // at least one of the urls matched the link
    }
}
```

But I can't integrate it with my larger code. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE #2 on August 29th**

In another post, someone also mentioned one of my function logic may be wrong. Unfortunately the person didn't get too far in the details.

[image]

**UPDATE #3 on August 29th**
O.K. I think I am close, I stepped through my code and added breakpoints and it appears that my code is looping through all the links *twice*

[image]
[image]

The screenshots show how `target _self` is being applied to the links like they're supposed to, but for some reason the loop runs again and just jumps to the else block, thus adding `target _blank` to all the links?

Here is the code again with the original for loop! Thanks!

```
for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {


  url = getURL(arguments[i]);
    for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
        link = container_links[j];

        if (link.href.indexOf(url) != -1) { //problem seems to be here
            parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = link.href;

            link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
            newPathName = parser.pathname;


            if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
                newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                newstr = newPathName;
                link.href = newstr;

            }
        } else {
            link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try `!==`?

Comment: Continuously [updating your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38919624/revisions) and asking about **new problems** made this question and its existing answer(s) a mess. Please consider rolling it back to version #1 (I'm just guessing here) and posting a **new question** for your new problem.

Comment: Actually they are not **new problems**; I have been updating everyone on the various findings/observations  while I have been trying to solve it. Funny thing since I have been making those updates, the question has been getting up votes everytime. However you may be right in regards to asking a new question reflecting the latest discovery.

Comment: Hi man, you could maybe add it to a jsfiddle or something all the code so we could play around with it, i think you will get the answer quicker with more people having the exact code to play around with

Comment: Hey Torean, I appreciate your help and good idea! https://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/1xomL42r/7/ The script is working except the `anchor` tags where I wanted to go to `target _self` are not getting any attribute value, e.g. no target attribute is being applied to those. If you have any questions give a holler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  multiple issues in your code, including logical. For example

```
function getURL() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        return URLS[arguments[i]];//always returns arguments[0]
    }
}
```

I rewrote it in such way that it takes and returns arrays (see jsfiddle below).
Next issue

```
  //root problem. this for loop See solution in JSFiffle
  for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) { // Using a for loop to allow unlimited arguments to be passed in
    url = getURL(arguments[i]); // We are calling the publicApi.getURL() method and passing the looped argument from above

    //and rewrite target again and again. I remove outer loop
    for (var j = 0, jlen = avon_rep_container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) { // This loop goes over the whole documents links...
      link = avon_rep_container_links[j];
      if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) { //...and we are checking each argument passed in to see if it matches the object value stored in the getURL function e.g. like a switch statement..
        parser = document.createElement('a'); //...if so we are essentially adding a blank tag to all the documents in the document
        parser.href = link.href;//parser isn't used 

        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');//will be changed in the next loop
        newPathName = parser.pathname;


        if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) { // Added check for these strings for SMO page
          newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
          newstr = newPathName;

        } else {
          newstr = newPathName;
        }
        link.href = newstr;
      } else {
        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

      }
    }
```

Lots of variables declared but not used. I didn't touch them.

The issue with `target` is fixed in the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexKudryashev/bu5ejguj/7/).

Answer (score 0):

**Edited!**

add id to your anchor `<a>` and try using `jQuery` to alter your `<a>` tag `target` attribute:

```
<a id="custom_target" href="http://foo.com/path/to_page.aspx"> 
    <img src="img/some_image.jpg">
</a>
```

and jQuery code to modify attribute:

```
if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
    $('#custom_target').attr('target', '_self');
}
else{
    $('#custom_target').attr('target', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arjun, but that didn't work. Like I mentioned it appears to slap the target blank to all of the `href` and it shouldn't!

Comment: Did you check the value of `link.href.indexOf(url)` ? is it returning -1?

Comment: Yes, because the pathnames are being changed.